# Pointers differ from an integer 2-D array and a string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

we all know that to define a 2-D array of strings we do

```
  char *c[5] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

or

```
char c1[][10] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

and when i get the value of one of these,we do `printf("%c ",c[1][0] ); //just example

but when declaring

```
int a[][3]={{20,60,30},{40,90,180},{200,880,900}}; //no problem with getting the output from
```

but when declaring

```
int (*a1)[3]={{20,60,30},{40,90,180},{200,880,900}};
```

and trying to get the output `printf("%i",a1[0][0]);`
the program is crash

i know that from the definition of (a) i can do as following

```
 int(*p)[3]=a; then printf("%i",p[0][0]);
```

and i also know if i do `int *a1[3]` then i create an array of pointers ,and to avoid that we put the parentheses,so why with the definition of `int(*a1)[3]` the program crash ? and how the compiler deal with it ? and what the difference between this case and the case of string `char *c[5]` it the same if i put `char (*c)[5]`and no problems happens with char ?

Comment: isn't it like `int (*a1)[3]` says _pointer to an array of 3 ints_, which is not your definition?

Comment: actually i got confused by the two definition int(*a1)[3] or int*a1[3] ,i think they both a pointer of a1 to array of 3 ints but the compilar treat them differently ,am i wrong ?

Comment: Crank up your compiler warnings. You are initializing a pointer-to-array with a load of integers.

Comment: Questions starting with "we all know ..." make me very suspiciously. And, yet again, the prerequisite is wrong. You are not generating a 2D array of strings, but an array of pointers to chars, let's call it a **1D** array of strings, but not 2D!

Comment: i am not an expert Mr.Olaf, i still in the beginning sorry for making you confused @Olaf

Comment: It takes more to confuse me. It is just a bad idea to start with such a sentence, even more if you post something actually _not_ known to all (even if it was correct). Just imagine I'd start like this and you notice you actually do **not** know. How would you feel - a bit dum*? (That is no offense, and I feel not offended either, but others might)

Comment: @Yahia Farghaly: `int (*a1)[3]={{20,60...` will not even compile. What "crash" are you talking about then?

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration

```
int (*a1)[3]={{20,60,30},{40,90,180},{200,880,900}};
```

`a1` is a pointer (to an array of 3 `int`s). You can't initialize it with the above initializer. You can understand this by taking an example

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *p = a;
```

You can't initialize `p` as

```
int *p = {1, 2, 3};
```

because `p` is a pointer, not arrays. That said pointers are not arrays.

You should note that the declaration

```
char *c[5] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

and

```
char c1[][5] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

are completely different with each other. 
Former declares `c` as an array of `5` pointers to `char`  while latter declares `c1` an array of arrays of `char`s.

Comment: @NatashaDutta; Yeah. Don't have time right now to fix that. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this declaration

```
char *c[5] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

does not declare a 2D array. It is a one-dimensional array of pointers to string literals.

This declaration

```
char c1[][10] = {"string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5"};
```

is indeed a declaration of a 2D array.

This declaration

```
int (*a1)[3]={{20,60,30},{40,90,180},{200,880,900}};
```

is invalid and the compiler should issue a diagnostic message. In this declaration `a1` is a scalar object and it may not be initialized by a list of initializers in braces when there are more than one initializer and moreover when there are enclosed initializers in braces.

A scalar object may be initialized by the brace list containing only one initializer as for example

```
int x = { 10 };
```

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression,
>   optionally enclosed in braces.

But you can do the following using compound literals

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int ( *a1 )[3] = ( int[][3] )
    { 
        { 20, 60, 30 }, 
        { 40, 90, 180 },
        { 200, 880, 900 }

    };  

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a1[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
20 60 30 
40 90 180 
200 880 900
```

In this program declaration `int ( *a1 )[3]` declares a pointer to an array of type `int[3]` . That is in the right side of the declaration there is a compound literal that has type `int [3][3]` (a 2D array) that is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and this value is assigned to `a1`